# Load an Url in Webview and get its response

Tags: android, webview, httpresponse

Iam loading a Url in my WebView. It is a login page. I want to find the response I get after I get authenticated after I enter my credentials on this login page.

This is what I have done so far:-

Login.java

```
wvLogin = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WVLogin);

// WebView settings
wvLogin.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvLogin.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

// Load url
wvLogin.loadUrl("myUrl");

// Set WebViewClient to load the url in webview and not phone's default browser.
wvLogin.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        redirected =view.getUrl();
        redirected=  Uri.decode(redirected);

        if (redirected != null && redirected.equals(redirectUri)) {
            wvLogin.stopLoading();
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Update.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)  {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

});
```

How do I go ahead with this?

Comment: Not much clear. what response you should get.? when u click on login button on ur site. it must redirect to some other page.

Comment: after entering login credential what u r getting? No need of redirecting ur page webview will handle that thing

Comment: Have you checked logcat for response?

Comment: @QadirHussain Iam expecting a token as a response afterI hit the login button

Comment: @Wizard I expect a Token after the credentials are entered

Comment: @StackOver what token?

Comment: @Wizard when the user is authenticated he is assigned an access token which I need for further requests.

Answer (score 3):

Try this --

set up a javascript interface

```
wvLogin.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvLogin.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
```

Get HTML tag in onPageFinished()

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
}
```

Add define your JS interface

```
//JavaScript interface
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    public void showHTML(String result) {
      String htmlString = result;
      //Do your stuff with the result
    }
}
```

This only works on API 17 and above

Comment: We need to add `@JavascriptInterface` annotation before showHTML function

Answer (score 1):

Make your login result page contain a meta-tag with token information you need.

In your activity setup your wvLogin:

```
_wvLogin.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

_wvLogin.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void saveMetaTag(final String name, final String value) {
        //Save meta tag value in some dictionary
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void onNoMoreMetaTags() {
        //Process meta tags
    }

}, "metaLoader");
```

Then read the metatags by executing javascript:

```
wvLogin.loadUrl("javascript:var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); if (metaTags != null && metaTags.length > 0) {var i; for (i=0;i<metaTags.length;i++) { window.metaLoader.saveMetaTag(metaTags[i].name, metaTags[i].content);  };  }; window.metaLoader.onNoMoreMetaTags();");
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to use WebViewClient. Something like **wvLogin.setWebChromeClient(new YourWebClient());**

```
String htmlContent = "";
private class YourWebClient extends WebViewClient{

    // you want to catch when an URL is going to be loaded
    public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading  (WebView  view, String  urlConection){
        URL aURL = new URL(url); 
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
        conn.connect(); 
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        htmlContent = convertToString(is);
    }

    public String convertToString(InputStream inputStream){
       StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       String line;
       try {
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             string.append(linea + "\n");
          }
       } catch (IOException e) {}
       return string.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before this gives me a blank webpage